# Glassfish - Application name is already in use

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

---

I’ve come to an hold with my programing because I’m getting an error from glassfish. I’m using NetBeans IDE 7.3 for this project. And I’ve built a simple program which runs over the web(jsp file etc). But I keep on getting the weirdest error display from glassfish. I’ve searched the internet for my solution and found people posting similar things, but I never seem actually manage to fix it because I don’t really understand the post which I’ve read.

### So what is the error that I get at startup? First time I run it I get this from the Output

> Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.2
>   GlassFish Server 3.1.2 is running.
>   In-place deployment at
>  C:\Users\Vedo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ÄrendeWebApplication\build\web
>   Initializing...
>   deploy?
>   DEFAULT=C:\Users\Vedo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ÄrendeWebApplication\build\web&name=ÄrendeWebApplication&contextroot=/_rendeWebApplication&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.1.2
>  
>   Error occurred during deployment: null. Please see server.log for more details.
>   C:\Users\Vedo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ÄrendeWebApplication\nbproject\build-
> impl.xml:1038: The module has not been deployed.
>   See the server log for details.

---

The actually name of the project is ÄrendeWebApplication and sure it’s a weird name for some people. 
Well anyhow I tried to run the application again just to make sure it’s not something spooky going on, and I got a totally different error message.

> In-place deployment at
>   C:\Users\Vedo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ÄrendeWebApplication\build\web
>   Initializing...
>   deploy?
>   DEFAULT=C:\Users\Vedo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ÄrendeWebApplication\build\web&name=Ärende
>   WebApplication&contextroot=/_rendeWebApplication&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.1.2
>  
>   Error occurred during deployment: Application name ÄrendeWebApplication is already in use.
>   Please pick a different name.. Please see server.log for more details.
>   C:\Users\Vedo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ÄrendeWebApplication\nbproject\build-
> impl.xml:1038: The module has not been deployed.
>   See the server log for details.

---

Alright so this is the weirdest part since it’s complaining that the name of my application is already in use? So I thought first it could perhaps be something with the database, but went to see the “Java DB Database Process” and it seemed fine, will post it too just in case

---

Fri Jun 07 11:01:10 CEST 2013 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Fri Jun 07 11:01:11 CEST 2013 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.8.2.2 - (1181258) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527

---

So the database is not the problem “I Believe” so I went later to check on the Glassfish server 3.1.2 and I found some warning messages which read

---

> WARNING: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0]
>  : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@297b0d9d].
>   WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@297b0d9d] from index [0] 
>   WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@572b43d] from index [1] 
>   INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ÄrendeDao: [java:global/ÄrendeWebApplication/ÄrendeDao!com.Ärende.dao.ÄrendeDaoLocal, java:global/ÄrendeWebApplication/ÄrendeDao]
>   INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [ÄrendeWebApplication] at [/_rendeWebApplication]
>   SEVERE: The log message is empty or null. Please log an issue against the component in the logger field.

---

And here is where I’ve tried different things, well I thought it first complained about the name, it’s alredy in use right…. So I deleted the application and moved it to another place on my hard drive and well, I wouldn’t be posting this if it worked. Then I started considering that perhaps the database was something wrong with, I went to the console admin in glassfish to check the connection and the Ping and showed me that it worked as it should. Also perhaps important information is that I’ve connected glassfish through MySQL, but I hardly believe that this is the problem. I then stumbled across someone saying that you could force “redeploy via Eclipse”  well first problem here is that I’m not using Esclipse and second problem is I’ve searched A LOT to find if there is a “Force redeploy in NetBeans” and that is not the easiest task in life. So I believe this is perhaps my last stop hopefully and maybe someone here could help me out.

Comment: Does your application name really contain non-ASCII characters (`Ä`rendeWebApplication)? I'm not sure if this is the reason for the above errors, but using special characters in resource names (classes, projects, folders, etc.) is not the best idea.

Comment: Yes I noticed that apperently haveing those characters can make it struggle for you when it comes to running the application! Thanks for the comment it actually helpt, I will have to keep it in mind not to use those special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some steps you can try:

1. Fix your projects name :3
2. If your problem is the one the question title suggests, undeploy your application first, then redeploy. You can easily undeploy and force redeploy in the Glassfish Admin Gui (`http://localhost:4848`).
3. If your application still does not work, update your question with proper formatted log messages of the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Actually just doing step number one fixed evreything! I didnt know that a project's name could actually cause errors like that. Something I should really keep in mind, Thanks for the quick answer and easy guide hope this also helps someone else!