# Can't deploy .war in Jelastic glassfish container at Layershift

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I'm experiencing failed trying to deploy my .war in Jelastic panel. No matter what I try in my code, the answer is always the same: failed to deploy. The glassfish instance is running on Layershift and the environment is: Java 1.7 and Glassfish 4.1. In my personal computer it's running smootly. I'm gluing the content of server.log below:

```
[2017-06-07T01:48:00.342+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800080342] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:00.469+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800080469] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:00.480+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800080480] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:00.482+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800080482] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:00.483+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800080483] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:00.485+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800080485] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:00.486+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800080486] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:01.117+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800081117] [levelValue: 900] [[
WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:01.127+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800081127] [levelValue: 900] [[
WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:01.138+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800081138] [levelValue: 900] [[
WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:01.570+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800081570] [levelValue: 800] [[
Registering the Jersey servlet application, named br.com.appihub.api.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig, at the servlet mapping /v1/*, with the Application class of the same name.]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:01.882+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800081882] [levelValue: 800] [[
Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...]]

[2017-06-07T01:48:02.689+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1496800082689] [levelValue: 800] [[
Loading application [ROOT] at [/]]]

[2017-06-07T01:59:52.148+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1496800792148] [levelValue: 900] [[
Context path from ServletContext: differs from path from bundle: /]]
```

Comment: Can you describe the failure? What actually happens and how is it different to what you expect? The log you posted is relatively normal and shows your app being deployed properly.

Comment: Might be a similar case to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986726/glassfish-application-name-is-already-in-use

Comment: Hello Mike, the problem is that the application is not deployed after the process, simply nothing happens, the context doens't keep fixed. The message I receive in the tab Action is: "remote failure Error occurred during deployment Application name api is already in use. Please pick a different name.. Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed."